# how to pass javascript parameter from asp.net to .focus

Tags: javascript, asp.net, parameter-passing

I´m a bit confused here. The thing is that I have an asp.net textbox that I want to tab to the next textbox when maxlength is true and the user does not hit certain keys. My asp.net code is like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txbTransferBanknumber" Style="width: 50px;" MaxLength="4" 
Visible="true" runat="server" autocomplete="off"    onkeyup="autoTabNextTextBox(this,'txbTransferLedger')" CssClass="AutoTabFill" />
```

my autoTabNextTextBox function looks like this:

```
function autoTabNextTextBox(sender, nextTextBox) {

    var keyCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode
    var mylength = $(sender).val().length;
    var maxlength = $(sender).attr('maxLength');

    if((keyCode != 37) && (keyCode != 39))
    {
        if ((keyCode != 8) && (keyCode != 16))
        {
            if (mylength == maxlength)
            {   
                $('.nextTextBox').focus();
                //nextTextBox.focus();                    
            }
        }
    }

}
```

How do I pass the parameter nextTextBox to .focus() ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'pass the parameter nextTextBox to .focus()'?

Comment: I´m just not understanding how to let my javascript focus on to the next textBox (txbTransferLedger) while my parameter name is NextTextBox.

Comment: Ok I see. Then please view answer from Luke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a [ClientIdMode](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/30/cleaner-html-markup-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-client-ids-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx) of Static (meaning the id of the output HTML element is `txbTransferLedger`) then you just need to include the nextTextBox **parameter** as part of the selector (as opposed to the **string** `nextTextBox` which you are currently using):

```
$('#' + nextTextBox).focus();
```

**Update:** If you cannot use a ClientIdMode of Static and therefore don't have full control over the generated ids of the input elements then another option is to use a class selector instead. Give each input element a unique class name (this can be in addition to any existing classes you are using) e.g.:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txbTransferLedger" CssClass="AutoFill TransferLedger" />
```

Then pass the the class name you want (`TransferLedger` in this example) into the `autoTabNextTextBox` function instead of the ID. You can then use a class selector as follows:

```
$('input.' + nextTextBox).focus(); // e.g. $('input.TransferLedger').focus();
```

Comment: I cant have the ClientIDMode set to static.
What other options do I have then ?